# Nokia MixRadio REST API fetching charts

Tags: rest, mixradio

I am using Nokia Mixradio REST api to get the charts. But i can request the charts for a particular country only. I want to get the charts for a particular genre of a particular country. Here's the request message which I am using currently. Is there a way to get the charts for a particular genre?
http://api.mixrad.io:80/1.x/in/products/charts/album?itemsperpage=50&startindex=0&client_id=eac56b8ec397c8a40a4c66ce703a70c5&domain=music

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have an API specifically for that, but you can get the information by searching for artists, albums or tracks for the specific genre - e.g. http://api.mixrad.io/1.x/in/?itemsperpage=50&startindex=0&client_id=eac56b8ec397c8a40a4c66ce703a70c5&domain=music&genre=Bollywood&category=album - more search options are documented here: http://dev.mixrad.io/doc/rest/public/Search.html